# Parse data, single to multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server

have a single column `Varchar(2000)`.

Data looks like in a single column,

```
12:10:08: Dialing12:10:08: Connecting12:10:08: ABC: abc:9433769781$100.88.77.0:878712:10:08: ABCD: 000012:10:09: Agent Initializing12:10:25: On Call12:10:25: Assigned to operator12:10:25: Waiting for Supervisor12:10:30: Waiting for Manager12:11:30: Call Ended12:11:30: Call Not connected..
```

I want to parse it like,

```
12:10:08: Dialing
12:10:08: Connecting
12:10:08: ABC: abc:9433769782$100.88.77.0:8787
12:10:08: ABCD: 0000
12:10:25: Agent Initializing
12:10:18: On Call
12:10:25: Assigned to operator
12:10:30: Waiting for Supervisor
12:10:30: Waiting for Manager
12:11:30: Call Ended
12:11:30: Call Not connected
```

Any help. Searched the complete forum, but I am really unsure about this, particularly an absence of a specific identifier. Appreciate your help.

P/S- This is just an example of a single time,time is not constant.

Comment: Where is this being rendered?  you could have the system rendering it replace the ': ' (Colon space) with a carriage return line feed (Chr(10) & chr(13)) I believe to have it go to a second line.  If you need a break after that do it twice using replace...  although `12:10:08: ABC: abc:9433769782$100.88.77.0:8787` would fail...

Comment: There are no fixed delimiters? You would need to split on hh:mm:ss ? Is you output a single string or 1 *row* per entry?

Comment: Are these fixed values (`Dialing`, `Connecting`, etc) in fixed order?

Comment: Yeesh.  I think you may need to use regular expressions to identify the timestamps, then substring out the text between them.

Comment: @Alex, there is no fix delimiters. to me hh:mm:ss is probably the best identifier, where to tell sql server, whenever you see hh:mm:ss break the line. its a single single string

Comment: @T.S.Tho are fixed values for some rows. but it will be better they are not as some can definitely change,

Comment: Yuck!!! This is why we want to have each set of datapoints in their own row. This is going to be a super ugly kludge at best. No matter how to parse this out there are going to be pieces that fall through the cracks.

Comment: @user3657257 are you *absolutely sure* there are no delimiters?  What do you get if you convert to varbinary(max)?  There may be a `CHAR(0)` or other non-printing delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuck.  But, you can do this with a recursive CTE.  Here is how:

```
with t as (
      select '12:10:08: Dialing12:10:08: Connecting12:10:08: ABC: abc:9433769781$100.88.77.0:878712:10:08: ABCD: 000012:10:09: Agent Initializing12:10:25: On Call12:10:25: Assigned to operator12:10:25: Waiting for Supervisor12:10:30: Waiting for Manager12:11:30: Call Ended12:11:30: Call Not connected.. ' as col
     ),
     cte as (
      select left(t.col, 9 + patindex('%[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]: %', substring(t.col, 11, 1000))) as val,
             substring(t.col, 10 + patindex('%[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]: %', substring(t.col, 11, 1000)), 1000) as rest
      from t
      where t.col like '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]: %[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]: %'
      union all
      select (case when rest like '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]: %[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]: %'
                   then left(rest, 9 + patindex('%[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]: %', substring(rest, 11, 1000)))
                   else rest
              end) as val,
             substring(rest, 10 + patindex('%[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]: %', substring(rest, 11, 1000)), 1000) as rest
      from cte
      where rest like '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]: %'
     )
select val
from cte;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20439).

Comment: I know its really awful, Thanks for all the effort Gordon. Lets try

Comment: @user3657257 . . . A problem like this is good practice for recursive CTEs ;)

Comment: Have a quick question Gordon. Actually the column name in actual table is "Customerlog" and table is Customerdetail. So, in the query,where to use the table name. I am probably messing up with virtual t and actual T.

Comment: @user3657257 . . . If you want to do this for multiple rows inside a table, you need an `id` for each row.  I would suggest that you set up a SQL Fiddle with sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative;

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1024) = '12:10:08: Dialing12:10:08: Connecting12:10:08: ABC: abc:9433769781$100.88.77.0:878712:10:08: ABCD: 000012:10:09: Agent Initializing12:10:25: On Call12:10:25: Assigned to operator12:10:25: Waiting for Supervisor12:10:30: Waiting for Manager12:11:30: Call Ended12:11:30: Call Not connected'

WITH T(last, pos) AS(
        SELECT 0, 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT pos, pos + PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@string, pos + 1, LEN(@string)))
        FROM T
        WHERE pos != last
    )
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, last, CASE WHEN pos = last THEN len(@string) ELSE pos - last END)
    FROM T
    WHERE LAST > 0
```

For

```
(No column name)
12:10:08: Dialing
12:10:08: Connecting
12:10:08: ABC: abc:9433769781$100.88.77.0:8787
12:10:08: ABCD: 0000
12:10:09: Agent Initializing
12:10:25: On Call
12:10:25: Assigned to operator
12:10:25: Waiting for Supervisor
12:10:30: Waiting for Manager
12:11:30: Call Ended
12:11:30: Call Not connected
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking for an SQL solution but I am not sure that is possible without a `while` loop and extensive string manipulation which is quite inefficient.

If you are happy to bring the original varchar down to the BLL level, you can do it here using a regular expression.  As I assume you want to do this in order to output to screen or log file then this should be possible.

For example: 
Replace

```
/([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}: ).*/gU
```

with

```
\n/1
```

Example:
http://regex101.com/r/eM4vD5/1

Comment: That can be another idea. lets try.